# Keeping an input focused when another select option is focused?

Tags: jquery, input, focus

I have a simple search form containing two inputs. A text input and a select input.

The text input is full width and the select input is positioned absolutely so it sits within the right hand side of the text input and acts as a section filter.

Examples here

[image: search-form]

What I'm trying to do is to keep the text input focused when the select element is being chosen. At the moment, you can focus on the text input but when you choose your select option the search/text input loses focus meaning you can't just hit return to search.

I'm assuming this is solvable with a little jQuery. I've found some examples that will keep the input focused (or refocuses it) when you click out of the input, but I only want it to remain focus when the select is being selected. Hope that makes sense?

Markup is like so...

```
<div id="search" class="global-search">

    <form class="global-search-form" method="post">

        <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">

        <div class="search-select">
            <span>in</span>
            <select name="select-category">
                <option value="all-categories">Everything</option>
                <option value="category1">Category 1</option>
                <option value="category2">Category 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: This is the easiest hack you can do : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/cuza0ugo/

Comment: Thanks for that. Was having an issue in Chrome with this though? I found `$('select').focus(function() {
  $('input').focus();
});` worked just as well.

Comment: You'll have problem with focus on the select since it would avoid selecting an option from that select. Try using click or change instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really *keep* the text input in focus while focusing the select, but you can refocus on change:

```
$('[name=select-category]').on('change', function(){
    $("[type=search]").focus();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/obbthcfp/

Comment: Thanks for this. As per my comment above, I found that focus event on the select element did the trick also.

Comment: Ah, didn't refresh to see comments as I wrote my answer. Whoops... Nice Shot! Nice Shot! Nice Shot! (sorry, flashed to rocket league for some reason).